# Horizontal Lines appearing in ContentDialog view

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a modal progress overlay in my Windows 8.1 app.

I have a class that creates a ContentDialog that fills the entire screen and is displayed ASynchronously as follows:

```
_contentDialog = new ContentDialog();
_contentDialog.FullSizeDesired = true;      // full screen
_contentDialog.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
_contentDialog.Background.Opacity = 0.7;    

 await _contentDialog.ShowAsync();
```

However this code is producing horizontal lines across the ContentDialog which I need to remove.

[image]

What is causing these lines to appear and how do I remove them?

Comment: Those lines are the transition effects when you first open the Dialog (it only last a very short time on a device).  When you close the dialog you will see that those lines reappear and does this falling animation downward, basically a pretty cool collapse animation.

Comment: Interesting, but sadly looks awful when not collapsing! Does using different navigation transitions remove these lines? 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345129/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions

Comment: To see what I mean add one with Add -> New Item -> Content Dialog, then in your code made an instance of that newly create Diaglog.  It will have default text and 2 buttons, click on the close button and watch the animation.  I was wondering if that screenshot is from the emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the background of the ContentDialog to transparent it'll make the lines disappear. Unfortunately, you can't have it black.

```
        _contentDialog = new ContentDialog();
        _contentDialog.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
```